# any idea about HTML Editor opensource

Tags: html

in my web application there is requirement to edit or modify the given web page, if is there any open source for HTML editor and you know please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking about javascript based in-page rich text editors that you'd attach to a CMS? Or are you referring to open source desktop text/html editors to edit HTML files?

Comment: @DA: javascript based in-page(browser based) rich text editors that i want to attach in my web application.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what you looking for, try this one

http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

or this [NVU](http://www.nvu.com/)

Comment: Quoth the OP: "in my web application there is requirement to edit or modify the given web page". Sounds to me like it needs to run in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. heh =)